# How can I display an image as a whole using ILI9488 and M0?

Tags: lcd

I'd like to display 4 random images out of 100 every day from the built in flash of my M0 microcontroller on my LCD (ILI9488).When I use DFRobot_GDL library "drawUDPicture" example, it only shows pictures line by line. I'm very new to coding. Can someone tell me what to add to the exmaple code to present 4 random images out of 100 and have the images appear right away and not line by line? Thank you so much!

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include "DFRobot_GDL.h"
#include "DFRobot_Picdecoder_SD.h"

DFRobot_Picdecoder_SD decoder;

//Custom communication pins
/*M0*/

#define TFT_DC  7
#define TFT_CS  5
#define TFT_RST 6

DFRobot_ILI9488_320x480_DMA_SPI screen(/*dc=*/TFT_DC,/*cs=*/TFT_CS,/*rst=*/TFT_RST);

void setup()
{
  //Initialize the serial port
  SerialUSB.begin(115200);
  //Initialize screen
  screen.begin();
  //Initialize the SD card, wait until the initialization is successful
  while(1)
  {
    if (SD.begin())
    {
      SerialUSB.println("initialization done.");
      break;
    }
    SerialUSB.println("initialization failed!");
  }
}


//Store file name of the icon in the read directory
char str[32];

void loop()
{
  /* Set the screen color to white */
  screen.fillScreen(COLOR_RGB565_WHITE);

  decoder.drawPicture(/*filename=*/"picture/219x220.jpg",/*sx=*/0,/*sy=*/0,/*ex=*/screen.width(),/*ey=*/screen.height(),/*screenDrawPixel=*/screenDrawPixel);
  screen.fillScreen(COLOR_RGB565_WHITE);
  decoder.drawPicture(/*filename=*/"picture/RGB565.bmp",/*sx=*/0,/*sy=*/0,/*ex=*/screen.width(),/*ey=*/screen.height(),/*screenDrawPixel=*/screenDrawPixel);

}

//For decoding function calling, this function is used to draw a pixel on the screen
void screenDrawPixel(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t color)
{
  //Draw a point on the screen
  screen.writePixel(x,y,color);
}
```

Comment: To speed things up, consider using a not-compressed image format that is compatible with the library you are using.  Also note that you are likely using a I2C serial device to store images and a serial device to display images.